# How can I make this example with java GUI JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

I want to make the tag (이름: 홍길동 학번: 1111111) looks like this,

이름:

홍길동

학번:

111111

but only I can make looks like this,

이름: 홍길동 학번: 111111

I made it to JLabel on SidePanel which extends JPanel. And \n is not working on JPanel I guess? ..and I don't know how to fix it.

Do I need to make some other JPanel on the SidePanel or use another Layout?? like.. Grid or null? or more JLabel??

**Here's my code.**

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

private JButton proscons = new JButton();
private JLabel tag = new JLabel();
private JLabel num = new JLabel();

MyFrame() {
    setTitle("융프2 기말고사");
    
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    cp.add(new WestPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
    cp.add(new MyPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); // 가운데서 GUI 창 뜨도록
    setSize(400, 400);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

class WestPanel extends JPanel {
    WestPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        setSize(100,400);
        add(proscons);
        proscons.setText("찬성");
        add(tag);
        tag.setText("이름: \n홍길동");
        add(num);
        num.setText("학번: \n11111111");
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    MyPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyFrame();
}
```

}

Comment: null layout is __always_ wrong! no screenshots of plain text please

Comment: Try using `<br>` instead of `\n` to indicate a line break.   See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *Do I need to ... use another Layout??* - yes. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for the basics. You can also nest panels with different layout managers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML text formatting in JLabels.

Try doing this:

```
tag.setText("<html>이름:<br>홍길동</html>");
num.setText("<html>학번:<br>11111111</html>");
```

Comment: It works, thanks! (and sorry for the late reply) <3